# Change timezone laptop and refresh page on Firefox not change use new Date() js

Tags: javascript, datetime, firefox, angular6

## Show time on Firefox:

- step1: I use new Date().toLocaleTimeString() in file demo.html
- step2: open file with firefox. and see time show "1:46:26 PM"
- step3: change timezone of laptop
- step4: reload page demo.html => time note change : "1:46:36 PM"
  (change when close/open page)

I want to ask it issue of firefox or my code?

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Did you try clearing your firefox cache before you opened up the file with firefox the second time? Does the same thing happen on google?

Comment: @Spangle Yes, I clear cache and open file on other tab but time not change with new timezone
only, close firefox and open agian => time change

Comment: I searching on gg and not yet

Comment: Does restarting Firefox update the page correctly? Maybe Firefox only reads the OS timezone on startup

Comment: @Ferrybig Yes, I think so